# UPDATE Doesn't Work Even Though I Get Success Response in Console

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table with that can be edited if an Edit button is pressed. You can then press the button again after changing information, and it runs an UPDATE query that should update the information in the database. In my console, it shows that all information is being read correctly and I even get a "Row Updated" response from my `console.log()`. However, the update is not read and updated in the database. What can be fixed in my code so that it will correctly update the row?

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Edit Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#html_master .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
   if($this.id != '.mr_id'){
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
   }
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    var dict = {}; 
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      console.log(type);
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
      switch (type) {
        case "mr_id":
          dict["MR_ID"] = value;
          break;
        case "mr_name":
          if (value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)) {
              dict["MR_Name"] = value;
          break;
          }
        case "buyer_id":
          if (!$.isNumeric(value)) {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
          }
          if (isValid) {
              dict["Buyer_ID"] = value;
          }
          break;
        case "poc_n":
          if (value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)) {
              dict["MR_POC_N"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_e":
          if (value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)) {
              dict["MR_POC_E"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_p":
          if (value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')) {
              dict["MR_POC_P"] = value;
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";
          }
          break;
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
        console.log(dict);
      $this.val('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
      var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update-copy.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row updated");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to updated");
            console.log(response);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
  }
});
```

Update php script:

```
<?php

  $MR_ID = $_POST['MR_ID'];
  $MR_Name = $_POST['MR_Name'];
  $Buyer_ID = $_POST['Buyer_ID'];
  $MR_POC_N = $_POST['MR_POC_N'];
  $MR_POC_E = $_POST['MR_POC_E'];
  $MR_POC_P = $_POST['MR_POC_P'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "UPDATE Stage_Rebate_Master SET MR_Name = :MR_Name, Buyer_ID = :Buyer_ID, MR_POC_N = :MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E = :MR_POC_E, MR_POC_P = :MR_POC_P WHERE MR_ID = :MR_ID";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue(':MR_ID', $MR_ID);
  $stmt->bindValue(':MR_Name', $MR_Name);
  $stmt->bindValue(':Buyer_ID', $Buyer_ID);  
  $stmt->bindValue(':MR_POC_N', $MR_POC_N);
  $stmt->bindValue(':MR_POC_E', $MR_POC_E);
  $stmt->bindValue(':MR_POC_P', $MR_POC_P);  
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

HTML/PHP:

```
  <body>

    <img src="image.png" id="image">

    <form> 
    Table Name: <input type="text" value="Stage_Rebate_Master" id="tableNameInput" readonly>
    <button class="create-user" id="insertButton">Add Vendor</button>
    </form>


<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Vendor">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<!-- Dialog box displayed after add row button is clicked -->
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" name="mr_name" id="mr_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="test">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="99">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_n" id="poc_n" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="name">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_e" id="poc_e" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="test@tst.com">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_p" id="poc_p" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="5555555555">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>



<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">  
<table id="html_master" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


<?php
    /* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>">
        <td class="mr_id" id="<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" id="mr_name-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" name="field" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" id="buy_id<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" id="poc_n-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" id="poc_e-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" id="poc_p-<?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't it look like update is not being commited? Just guessing

Comment: Not sure...I had this working before, but now its not working again. I am not familiar with the committing

Comment: Try using $pdo->beginTransaction(); before insert and then commit through $pdo->commit();

Comment: that doesnt seem to be working